# nullable displaytext

Tags: jqgrid

On colModel, is there any way to set the default value if the result is null, I mean:

```
colModel: [
{ name: 'Date', index: 'Date', width: 35, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m H:i' }, sorttype: 'date', **IFISNULLDISPLAY: '-'** }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems for me that you found a bug in iqGrid. [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.0/js/grid.base.js#L979) the variable `opts` will be set to

```
var opts= {rowId: rowId, colModel:cm, gid:ts.p.id, pos:colpos };
```

then inside of date formatter (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L333)) the `opts` will be extended to `op` with respect of `formatoptions`

```
op = $.extend({},op,opts.colModel.formatoptions);
```

and in case of non-empty `cellval` will be used `op`

```
return  $.fmatter.util.DateFormat(op.srcformat,cellval,op.newformat,op);
```

The bug is that in [another line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L343) which will be executed for empty `cellval` it will be used `opts` instead of `op`

```
return $.fn.fmatter.defaultFormat(cellval, opts);
```

The line (it has the number 5054 and 5052 in the file `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) must be fixed to

```
return $.fn.fmatter.defaultFormat(cellval, op);
```

How you can see from [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DefaultDate.htm) the `defaultValue: '-'` of the `formatoptions` of the [formatter: 'date'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) will work correct, but it is still not documented.

Comment: My question was about date, but i wanted to question about every type, not just for date

Comment: @Alexandre: If you look at [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) you will see which predefined formatter supports `defaultValue` property. I shows you *how to change the code of jqGrid to support the `defaultValue` property* for the `date` type. If you look at the code of [jquery.fmatter.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jquery.fmatter.js) and search for `$.fn.fmatter.defaultFormat` you will see that the same changes you can make for the most other formatters to add support of `defaultValue`.